# Как связать результаты запроса к базе данных и формы в Flask?

Tags: flask, orm, html-form, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

Есть приложение, написанное с использованием Flask, flask-wtf и flask-sqlalchemy, часть которого реализует общение с базой данных с схемой:
[image: schema]
Я пытаюсь сделать страничку, на которой бы выводились все строки таблицы staff, возможно отфильтрованные используя значения из формы. Эта часть понятна.
 
Дальше я хочу, чтобы рядом с каждой выведенной строкой была форма, состоящая из SelectMultipleField и SubmitField, где я мог бы выбрать категории, которые хочу добавить этой "строке" и по нажатию на кнопку добавить всё это в базу данных без перезагрузки страницы. Примерно так:
[image: example]
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как динамически, в зависимости от того, какие строки выбрались из базы данных, отобразить формы и самое главное, как эти формы связать с конкретной строкой таблицы, чтобы понимать, куда именно добавлять категории. Также не понятно, как обрабатывать нажатие кнопки, то есть куда перенаправлять или что вообще делать, чтобы изменения в базе данных произошли в фоновом режиме. 
Как сейчас реализована view-функция:

```
@app.route('/show_staff', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def show_staff():
    form = SelectStaffForm()
    query = Staff.query
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        gender_data = form.gender.data
        if gender_data is not None:
            query = query.filter(Staff.gender == gender_data)
        age = form.age.data
        if age is not None:
            query = query.filter(Staff.age >= age)
        salary = form.salary.data
        if salary is not None:
            query = query.filter(Staff.salary >= salary)
        date = form.employment_date.data
        if date is not None:
            query = query.filter(Staff.employment_date >= date)
    staff = query.all()
    categories = Category.query.all()
    category_choose_forms = {}
    for s in staff:
        choose_form = CategoryChooseForm()
        choose_form.category_name.choices=[(c.category_id, c.category_name) for c in categories]
        category_choose_forms[s.staff_id] = choose_form
    return render_template('showStaff.html', title='Show staff', staff=staff, form=form,
                           category_choose_forms=category_choose_forms)
```

CategoryChooseForm:

```
class CategoryChooseForm(FlaskForm):
    category_name = SelectMultipleField('Category')
    submit_categories = SubmitField('Submit Categories')
```

Шаблон на html-странице:

```
{% for s in staff %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ s.first_name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ s.second_name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ s.gender }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ s.age }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ s.salary }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="" method="post">
            {{ category_choose_forms[s.staff_id].hidden_tag() }}
                <p>
                    {{ category_choose_forms[s.staff_id].category_name.label}}<br>
                    {{ category_choose_forms[s.staff_id].category_name(size=3, style="width:200px",
                                id=s.staff_id, class_="js-example-basic-multiple categories-drop-down") }}
                    {% for error in category_choose_forms[s.staff_id].category_name.errors %}
                        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {{ category_choose_forms[s.staff_id].submit_categories }}
                </p>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

ORM:

```
class Staff(db.Model):
    staff_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    second_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    gender = db.Column(db.String(64))
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    salary = db.Column(db.Integer)
    employment_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    dismissal_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    category_link = db.relationship('StaffCategoryLink', backref='staff', lazy='dynamic')

class StaffCategoryLink(db.Model):
    staff_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('staff.staff_id'), primary_key=True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.category_id'), primary_key=True)

class Category(db.Model):
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    category_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    staff_link = db.relationship('StaffCategoryLink', backref='category', lazy='dynamic')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша view-функция написана неправильно.
Она всегда возвращает все строки таблицы: 
staff = query.all()
При том, что при запросе POST вы хотите возвращаем данные фильтровать. 
По видимому, вы не до конца понимаете, как работает используемый вами ORM.